# How to configure tslint or prettier to remove whitespace between if/while/for and ()?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint, prettier

I'm setting up react project and format my code with tslint, prettier and tslint-config-prettier. Also autoFormat with vscode.

How can I remove space between if/while/for and parenthese like 'if()' not 'if ()'?

I couldn't find the option related with this in tslint and prettier. But I found ['keyword-spacing'](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/keyword-spacing.html) in eslint. So I expect tslint and prettier to inclue something like keyword-spacing.

tslint.json

```
{
    "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
    "linterOptions": {
        "exclude": [
            "config/**/*.js",
            "node_modules/**/*.ts",
            "coverage/lcov-report/*.js"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "class-name": true,
        "comment-format": [true, "check-space"],
        "curly": true,
        "interface-name": false,
        "interface-over-type-literal": false,
        "jsx-boolean-value": false,
        "no-console": false,
        "no-duplicate-variable": true,
        "no-empty-interface": true,
        "no-internal-module": true,
        "no-var-keyword": true,
        "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
        "ordered-imports": false
    }
}
```

.prettierrc

```
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "quotes": true,
    "jsxSingleQuote": false
}
```

settings.json (in vscode for reference)

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "tslint.enable": true,
    "tslint.jsEnable": true,
    "tslint.alwaysShowRuleFailuresAsWarnings": true,
    "tslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "tslint.autoFixOnSave": true
}
```

expected:

```
let i: number = 0;
if(i <= 10) {
    i++;
}
```

actual:

```
let i: number = 0;
if (i <= 10) {
    i++;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We should note that shortly after this question was asked, **[TSLint was announced as being deprecated](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534)**. Nobody should use it anymore. [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io) is its replacement and successor.

TSLint had a rule called [`whitespace`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/whitespace) to enforce spacing. That rule had options such as `check-branch` for branching statements (`if`/`else`/`for`/`while`).

These days, the recommended approach for formatting is to use [Prettier](https://prettier.io) separately from ESLint. Its default options will enforce something similar to the spacing conventions being asked for in this question.

```bash
npx -y prettier some/file.ts --write
```

To get *no* spaces around braces, use its [`bracket-spacing` option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options#bracket-spacing). See that options page for other options you may want to customize.